# Could not resolve view with name 'streamrecords' in servlet with name 'spring'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, tomcat7

I am using a simple stream interger number from controller example using **Spring 4, Java 8, Tomcat 7**.

**CODE:**

```
package com.entrib.emg.server.controller.rest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@Controller
public class StreamRecordsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/streamrecords", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StreamingResponseBody handleRequest ()
            throws Exception {

        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Override
            public void writeTo (OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    out.write((Integer.toString(i) + " - ")
                                        .getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Type Exception Report

Message Could not resolve view with name 'streamrecords' in servlet with name 'spring'

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'streamrecords' in servlet with name 'spring'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

**BELOW IS THE SNAPSHOT:**

[image]

**QUESTION:**

What am I missing over here.

**EXPECTATIONS:**

This is just a simple rest API code, I am expecting a stream of integers streamed from this controller when the API is hit from either browser or postman.

**------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATED**

**------------------------------------------------**

When I added `@ResponseBody`, I am getting below error,

```
Type Status Report

Description The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing @ResponseBody on your servlet method or alternatively you can mark your class with @RestController

Comment: Thanks for your time. When added `@ResponseBody` , I m getting error which is updated in above post. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the annotation of your class to @RestController